# How to define the return type of `callEndPoint` appropriately?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, haskell, monad

In homework of week4, I refactored my solution:

```
payTrace :: Integer -> Integer -> EmulatorTrace ()
payTrace payment1 payment2 =  do
contract1 <- activateContractWallet (knownWallet 1) payContract
let pkh2 = mockWalletPaymentPubKeyHash $ knownWallet 2
callEndpoint @"pay" contract1 $ PayParams
   {
       ppRecipient = pkh2
   ,   ppLovelace = payment1
   }
void $ Emulator.waitNSlots 1
callEndpoint @"pay" contract1 $ PayParams
   {
       ppRecipient = pkh2
   ,   ppLovelace = payment2
   }
void $ Emulator.waitNSlots 1
```

to:

```
payTrace :: Integer -> Integer -> EmulatorTrace ()
payTrace payment1 payment2 =  do
contract1 <- activateContractWallet (knownWallet 1) payContract
let pkh2 = mockWalletPaymentPubKeyHash $ knownWallet 2
    payTo :: (Member RunContract effs) => PaymentPubKeyHash -> Integer -> Eff effs ()
    payTo pkh amount = callEndpoint @"pay" contract1 $ PayParams
       {
           ppRecipient = pkh
       ,   ppLovelace = amount
       }
payTo pkh2 payment1
void $ Emulator.waitNSlots 1
payTo pkh2 payment2
void $ Emulator.waitNSlots 1
```

(https://gitlab.com/moment-4/courses/plutus-pioneer/plutus-pioneer-program/-/blob/week04/code/week04/src/Week04/Homework.hs)

However, there are still 2 things I don't like about my current solution:

1. I'd prefer to put the `payTo` function in the where clause, but that doesn't seem to work properly (although I think I'm close thanks to Luis (https://discord.com/channels/826816523368005654/834340082273878046/942064349831381042). How would one define it in the where clause? (The solution of Luis put me on the right track, but I still can't get it right)
2. I still get compiler warnings about the type. How to define the type of the function properly, so I can get rid of the warnings as well?

```
src/Week04/Homework.hs:46:18: warning: [-Wsimplifiable-class-constraints]
    • The constraint ‘Member RunContract effs’ matches
        instance (Data.OpenUnion.Internal.FindElem t r,
                  Data.OpenUnion.Internal.IfNotFound t r r) =>
                 Member t r
          -- Defined in ‘Data.OpenUnion.Internal’
      This makes type inference for inner bindings fragile;
        either use MonoLocalBinds, or simplify it using the instance
    • In the type signature:
        payTo :: (Member RunContract effs) =>
                 PaymentPubKeyHash -> Integer -> Eff effs ()
      In the expression:
        do contract1 <- activateContractWallet (knownWallet 1) payContract
           let pkh2 = mockWalletPaymentPubKeyHash $ knownWallet 2
               payTo ::
                 (Member RunContract effs) =>
                 PaymentPubKeyHash -> Integer -> Eff effs ()
               ....
           payTo pkh2 payment1
           void $ Emulator.waitNSlots 1
           ....
      In an equation for ‘payTrace’:
          payTrace payment1 payment2
            = do contract1 <- activateContractWallet
                                (knownWallet 1) payContract
                 let pkh2 = ...
                     ....
                 payTo pkh2 payment1
                 ....
   |
46 |         payTo :: (Member RunContract effs) => PaymentPubKeyHash -> Integer -> Eff effs ()
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Ok, 8 modules loaded.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you expect but there are three ways to get rid of warnings:

1. add `{-# LANGUAGE MonoLocalBinds     #-}`, like the warning hints
2. don't give a type for `payTo` and let Haskell infer it
3. if things worked before, the body of `payTo` was fine in the `EmulatorTrace` monad, so you could go for `payTo :: PaymentPubKeyHash -> Integer -> EmulatorTrace ()`

I'm not particularly fond of the idea of moving the function in a `where` clause if it depends on something you obtain in the body of the bigger function. You could consider adding another parameter and passing `contract1` as an argument, and then you can move it to `where`.

Comment: Allright, thanks. Well, I just wanted to get rid of the warning and understand why it's there. So, seeing your solutions: 1. what does it mean (`MonoLocalBinds`)? 2. I try to understand the types passed everywhere. Is there no way I can give the right type signature? 3. The body was fine, but moving it to the where, makes in different (it's a different type in the do-bindings vs in the were clause.
That being said, it makes more sense to keep in the `let`-binding? (Just trying to figure out the Haskell type system and monads and do-bindings)

Comment: 1. a Haskell extension meant to infer less polymorphic types. Details here: https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/let_generalisation.html. 2. I'd say using `EmulatorTrace ()` for the result is the right type signature. The type you use is more general: `(Member RunContract effs) => ... -> Eff effs ()` can be specialized to `Eff '[StartContract, RunContract, Assert, Waiting, EmulatorControl, EmulatedWalletAPI, LogMsg String, Error EmulatorRuntimeError] ()`, which is `EmulatorTrace ()`, because RunContract is in the list of effects for EmulatorTrace thus the condition holds.

Comment: And 3, you use `contract1` in the body of `payTo` and if you move `payTo` to the `where` clause, `contract1` is no longer in scope, as it is local to the body of `payTrace`. Either leave `payTo` in the `let`-binding or make `payTo :: ContractHandle w s e -> PaymentPubKeyHash -> Integer -> EmulatorTrace ()`, move it to `where` and add `contract1` to the calls of `payTo` in the body of `payTrace`.